# IIS 7 Handler config not working with an App_Code source in Pipeline mode

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web-config, httphandler

I have an iframe that I am trying to dynamically load with a PDF using a handler to intercept the URL and select the correct PDF based on URL parameters. 
I have created a handler in my App_Code folder and a handler entry in my web.config file to handle "*.PDF" requests. The code and process works in debug, but I get a stack trace in the server saying the type "PDFHandler" couldn't be loaded. I am using visual studio 2015.

I've tried a couple different versions of the DLL, both with/without an assembler call. After reading this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx

Apparently I would no longer need to specify an assembly because all of the source code for the handler is in the App_Code folder. I tried this last night in the following setup:

```
    <httpHandlers>
          <add verb="*" path="*.pdf" type="PDFHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>

    <handlers>
            <add name="PdfHandler" path="*.pdf" verb="*" type="PDFHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
```

After no luck with removing the assembly and pulling the source code into the project, I have also tried to simplify the handler class to simply return upon being called instead of doing any actual work. Still getting an error on the server. The handler is implementing IHttpHandler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did:

Took the `App_Code` VB classes that I was attempting to run during a handler call and created a separate VB project. Built this one and put a reference on my site. Works fine that way.

Comment: Why edit the answer but not the original comment? Do points not get attributed to you that way?